# Why Ag-grid cell renderer is getting re-initialized on horizontal scrolling (on moveable columns)?

Tags: date, field, ag-grid, scrollable, cellrenderer

**While scrolling moveable columns cell renderer is getting re-initialized due to which the value in ag grid are getting reset. I need solution for this as I am not able to save row data as values gets reset on scrolling.**

```
agInit(params): void {
        this.params = params.data;
        this.rowIndex = params.rowIndex;
        this.selectedReason = params.data;
        if (this.params.proposedCompletionDateInFormat) {
            this.calender.selectedDateTime.startDate = new Date(params.data.proposedCompletionDateInFormat);
        } else {
            this.calender.selectedDateTime = null;
        }
        
        if(params.data.taskProgressState === "COMPLETED") {
            this.disableField = true;
          } else {
            this.disableField = false;
          }
    }

    refresh(params?: any): boolean {
        this.formGroup = params.context.formGroup;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add
[suppressColumnVirtualisation]="true" flag